# Can I use the Collections Groupings in Font Book within Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, font-management

I love how Font Book allows me to organize my fonts into collections like Fun, Modern, Swash-y, Sans Serif, etc...What I want to do is browse or filter fonts in Adobe Illustrator using those collections that I have so painstakingly curated in Font Book. Is that possible? Can someone please make an app that does that?

Comment: Hi bcolmer, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support or basic software education. Have you tried looking online for a tutorial, and if yes, what did you find? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. You can also take a look at the [help] if you're not sure how to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

**No** it is not possible. Adobe applications do *not* honor any menu configurations for the font menus.

Adobe seems to think they *know* exactly how it should always be sorted and doesn't allow for modification.

Comment: @bcolmer this is part of the reason why a lot of third party developers, especially font manager developers offer plugins for indesign, illustrator and photoshop: Suitcase Fusion, FontExplorer, TypeDna. There are also some stand-alone extensions.

Comment: Most plug ins no longer edit the menus within applications either. They do allow you to turn on and off fonts, but you can't control how fonts are grouped in the application menus.